# IOS - Adding shadowed border to image makes it heavy and unresponsive

Tags: ios, border, shadow

I am developing an iPad application.
In my application users can move, rotate and scale images.
I've noticed that when I add a 3d shadowed border to the images, it makes them incredibly heavy and unresponsive. I add the border using this code:

```
self.layer.MasksToBounds = false;
self.layer.ShadowColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
self.layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
self.layer.ShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.5f);
```

Why does this happen? What ways do I have to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known problem with CALayer shadows. Set the `shadowPath` property as well and you will see a good performance boost.

The shadow path can just be a path of the bounds of your image view. You should be able to just set it once and the layer transforms will keep it up to date as your image is scaled etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should also set

```
self.layer.ShouldRasterize = YES
```

Which will rasterize the layer. If this is set to NO (default) all the filters and the shadows that are applied on the Layer will be recalculated several times which costs quite much performance. Especially in scrollviews or tableviews.

Comment: Hi Lukas, one suggestion to make your answer stand out more is to add more information about what that does. Others who visit this question and answer would potentially learn more from your answer and upvote! Good luck! :)